# Omnistudio flexcard doesn't render properly in a different sandbox

Tags: omnistudio

I created a omnistudio child card with a dynamic rendering condition as below:

[image]

debtType is coming from the payload and Parent.loanType is an attribute passing from parent card.

This is not rendering well in the target sandbox. Nothing is showing. To debug into it, I removed the conditions and added both {debtType} and {Parent.loanType} into outputText in the card and test. Both of them seem to have correct values.

Further more, the same config is working in my dev sandbox, rendering everything perfectly. But when I deploy them into the target sandbox it is showing well. We are using mocks for the input so the input are pretty much identical too.

May I know if there is anything I missed here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this happens if you have developed this on your local org with `Managed Package Runtime` as enabled. And in your target org `Managed Package Runtime` might be disabled.

There are many other things which we loose when we disable `Managed Package Runtime` from `OmniStudio Settings` in setup.

I tried the same.

With `Managed Package Runtime` **disabled**:

Child Card :
[image]

Parent Card:
[image]

And preview does not render the child card. Whereas `displayValueText` from parent and `displayValue` from child both are true.

[image]

With `Managed Package Runtime` **enabled**.

Same child card and parent card preview displays properly.

Preview:
[image]